# citation DIN 1505 Teil 2 or DIN ISO 690

Tags: bibtex, citing

I am using texmaker under Ubuntu. I need to use `DIN 1505 Teil 2` or `DIN ISO 690` for bibliography. Which means in the text and for referencing a citation I want to have `[Author name, year]`. At the time it shows me numbers.
for example:

```
I want to use this[writer,2015].
```

at the time it looks like:
     I do not want this[1].
 My bibliography is in a biblio.bib file, and the tex file looks like:

```
\usepackage{natbib}
 .
 .
 .
 .
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{biblio}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\bibliographystyle{alpha}`? In case you are german speaking: [wichtige Hinweise zur Erstellung von Literaturverzeichnissen](http://golatex.de/wichtige-hinweise-erstellung-von-literaturverzeichnissen-t11964.html).

Comment: See also [Bibliography style DIN 1505 T2](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/207627/35864), [Suppress \unspace command to force biblatex to add spaces (DIN 1505)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/130448/35864), [Is there a BibLaTeX equivalent for the BibTeX style “alphadin” for the DIN 1505 Standard](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/124473/35864), [How to create bibliography for german thesis, preferably according to the german standard DIN~1505 with biblatex?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/23321/35864), [How to use ISO-690-2 format for BibTex?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/168179/35864)

Comment: There is the [`dinat` style for `natbib`](http://mirror.hmc.edu/ctan/biblio/bibtex/contrib/german/dinat/dinat-index.html) which apparently is no longer supported and `natdin` is preferred ([p. 15 in `l2tabu`](ftp://ftp.rrzn.uni-hannover.de/pub/mirror/tex-archive/info/l2tabu/german/l2tabu.pdf)) here: https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/biblio/bibtex/contrib/german/din1505. See also http://michael.glaess.eu/j/artikel/2-latex/16-erstellung-abkuerzungsverzeichnis-in-latex.html, http://www.golatex.de/wie-zitiert-man-mittels-biblatex-nach-din-1505-t6550.html.

Comment: I have removed the TeXmaker tag (the editor has no bearing on the bibliography style) and the `biblatex` tag (for now) since you seem to be using `natbib`/normal BibTeX `.bst` styles.

Comment: thanks a lot. If I have understand it correctly, I need to put natdin somewhere in latex path. Do you know how I can do it under ubuntu 14.04?

Comment: Did you install TeXLive via the package manager or did you get [a vanilla TeXLive](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1092/35864) which is highly recommended over the version from the package sources? Please see [Best way to install packages for TeXLive in Ubuntu?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/28528/35864) in the former case.

Comment: grate information. I updated my texLive with synaptic and used dinat style as you said. It works perfectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as classic BibTeX styles go, you could use [`natdin`](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/biblio/bibtex/contrib/german/din1505) with `natbib` ([`l2tabu`](ftp://ftp.rrzn.uni-hannover.de/pub/mirror/tex-archive/info/l2tabu/german/l2tabu.pdf) prefers using `natdin` over `dinat`, see p. 15.) or any of the other styles of [`din-1505`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/din1505).

There are also the `.bst` styles of the [`germbib` bundle](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/biblio/bibtex/contrib/germbib/bst), those styles need to be used with the [`bibgerm` package](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/biblio/bibtex/contrib/germbib/styles) which is also part of the bundle. (See [here](http://michael.glaess.eu/j/artikel/2-latex/16-erstellung-abkuerzungsverzeichnis-in-latex.html))

If you want to use [`biblatex`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex), you can use either [`BibLaTeX-DIN1505`](https://github.com/domhardt/BibLaTeX-DIN1505) or [`biblatex-iso690`](https://github.com/michal-h21/biblatex-iso690), both of which are not on CTAN as far as I know.